# Script pulls Users from OUs which is excluded

Tags: powershell

Not sure if anyone can assist. I have a script which pulls from AD all users not part of a Security group. This script uses $excludeOUs to exclude OU's with accounts which don't need to be in this group. However when i run this it seems to generate a few accounts mainly  Healthmailbox but the OU they sit in it seems to show them in the report. Is there some form of command that needs to be added to exclude these.

```
# create a regex from an array of OUs to exclude by 'OR-ing' them with the pipe character
$excludeOUs = ('OU=Exchange','OU=Support Accounts','OU=Terminated Users and Computers do not use',
               'OU=TerminatedEmployeesContractors','OU=TestAccounts','OU=Contractors and Consultants',
               'OU=MIS Users and Groups','OU=Service Accounts','OU=Security Groups','OU=Users',
               'OU=Testing','OU=Microsoft Exchange System Objects','OU=Microsoft Exchange Security Groups',
               'OU=CorpServiceAccounts','OU=Elevated','OU=***','OU=*** Assets','OU=Monitoring Mailboxes','OU=Users','OU=Q_Users','OU=Microsoft Exchange System Objects' | ForEach-Object {[Regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'

$ExportPath = 'c:\app\UsersNotinSG.csv'

# get a list of objects not having any of the excluded OUs in their DistinguishedName
# and at the same time output objects with properties 'User' and 'Groups'
 $grp=(Get-ADGroup 'SG_********').DistinguishedName
Get-ADUser -Filter { -not (memberof -eq $grp) -and (enabled -eq $true) } -Properties MemberOf | 
              Where-Object {$_.DistinguishedName -notmatch $excludeOUs} |
              Select-Object @{Name = 'User'; Expression = {$_.Name}},
                            @{name =  "OU";expression={$_.DistinguishedName.split(',')[1].split('=')[1]}}|
                            Export-Csv $ExportPath -NoTypeInformation
```

Thanks

Comment: the `-match` operator requires regex ... and you have given it an array, not a regex OR statement. try using  `-in` instead.

Comment: HealthMailboxes* are in `CN=Monitoring Mailboxes` rather than `OU=`

Comment: @AdminOfThings that did it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HealthMailboxes* are in CN=Monitoring Mailboxes rather than OU= – AdminOfThings